# double slash apache configuration

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

i'm deploying a ror application and now i have to rewrite the url (in apache) to

- add a prefix www to the url
- add / to the end of the url

So i took the following approach:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that it is appending two trailing slash to my url
So for example a resource /question/ask are becoming:

```
http://foo.com//question/ask
```

I tried to add the following Rule before all my Rewrite rules to try to remove the double //:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^//
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/+(.*) http://www.foo.com/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

but it didnt work.. any idea to rip off all extras "//" added to the url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$1` will include a `/` at the beginning. You probably want

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo.com$1 [R=301,L]
```